# target _blank close directly after open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following a href:

```html
<a href="http://homepage.com/f/_VKKyrH1bUYk/movie.avi" target="_blank"><img class="link" src="picture.png"></a>
```

When I click on it, it open for a second the new tab and after this it close directly!
I want that the tab don't close after click.
When the href looks like this. There is now problem:

```
<a href="http://homepage.com/f/VKKyrH1bUYk/movie.avi" target="_blank"><img class="link" src="picture.png"></a>
```

The problem I think is the underscore in the href. But I can't remove the underscore_ from the href!

Comment: Works for me fine. You probably have a local browser setting throwing you off.

Comment: I think the browser is preventing it for security reasons. I had the same problem but never figured out how to solve it (except for the open in new tab alternative of course but that's hideous, you have to right click and choose everytime).

Comment: It is not because of the underscore. It is because you are targeting a file with your link. The browser simply downloads it and closes the new (empty) page.

Comment: But what can I change in the code? It is not a download!

Comment: I experienced this issue as well. In my case it was an adblocker extension. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable AdBlocker extension or try doing the same in incognito private mode.